# FragmentTrasaction issue: IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

This error occurs during Fragment transaction from an Activity to Fragment. I did this process many times before, so I have no idea what I am missing. I read solutions for previous issues but couldn't find a one that's relevant. The transaction is done through a callback method from an Adapter.

**The final stack trace** (the part that's painted red)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.countriesdata, PID: 14691
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070063 (com.example.countriesdata:id/fragments_container) for fragment CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**The stack trace from the beginning of the problem**

```
E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f070063 (com.example.countriesdata:id/fragments_container) for fragment CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
    Activity state:
D/FragmentManager:   Local Activity cc8ca22 State:
        mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
        mChangingConfigurations=false
D/FragmentManager:     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h659dp 420dpi nrml port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1794) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=standard mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.1}
        mLoadersStarted=true
        Active Fragments in 32b8a64:
D/FragmentManager:       #0: ReportFragment{938c5c1 #0 androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag}
            mFragmentId=#0 mContainerId=#0 mTag=androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag
            mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
            mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
            mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
            mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
            mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{32b8a64 in HostCallbacks{db33166}}
            mHost=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
D/FragmentManager:         Child FragmentManager{93d4ca7 in ReportFragment{938c5c1}}:
              FragmentManager misc state:
                mHost=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
                mContainer=android.app.Fragment$1@c9eb554
                mParent=ReportFragment{938c5c1 #0 androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag}
                mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
          #1: RequestManagerFragment{dcafcfd #1 com.bumptech.glide.manager}
            mFragmentId=#0 mContainerId=#0 mTag=com.bumptech.glide.manager
D/FragmentManager:         mState=5 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
            mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
            mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
            mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
            mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{32b8a64 in HostCallbacks{db33166}}
            mHost=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
            Child FragmentManager{130fdf2 in RequestManagerFragment{dcafcfd}}:
D/FragmentManager:           FragmentManager misc state:
                mHost=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
                mContainer=android.app.Fragment$1@a680c43
D/FragmentManager:             mParent=RequestManagerFragment{dcafcfd #1 com.bumptech.glide.manager}
                mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
        Added Fragments:
          #0: ReportFragment{938c5c1 #0 androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag}
D/FragmentManager:       #1: RequestManagerFragment{dcafcfd #1 com.bumptech.glide.manager}
        FragmentManager misc state:
          mHost=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
          mContainer=android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks@db33166
          mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
      ViewRoot:
        mAdded=true mRemoved=false
        mConsumeBatchedInputScheduled=false
D/FragmentManager:     mConsumeBatchedInputImmediatelyScheduled=false
        mPendingInputEventCount=0
        mProcessInputEventsScheduled=false
        mTraversalScheduled=false    mIsAmbientMode=false
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePreImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
D/FragmentManager:     android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePostImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
      Choreographer:
        mFrameScheduled=false
        mLastFrameTime=69579192 (3737 ms ago)

    InsetsController:
        InsetsState
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_BOTTOM_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT frame=[0,1794][1080,1920] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT frame=[0,0][1080,63] visible=true
D/FragmentManager:       InsetsSource type=TYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES frame=[1080,0][1080,1920] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_LEFT_GESTURES frame=[0,0][0,1920] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_BOTTOM_GESTURES frame=[0,1794][1080,1920] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_TOP_GESTURES frame=[0,0][1080,63] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_SIDE_BAR_1 frame=[0,1794][1080,1920] visible=true
          InsetsSource type=TYPE_TOP_BAR frame=[0,0][1080,63] visible=true
      View Hierarchy:
        DecorView@dbd2c0[ListActivity]
          android.widget.LinearLayout{84f6bf9 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1794}
D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{84d073e G.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020194 android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
            android.widget.FrameLayout{8f5299f V.E...... ........ 0,63-1080,1794}
              androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{30b5aec V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1731 #7f070054 app:id/decor_content_parent}
                androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout{11ceb5 V.E...... ........ 0,147-1080,1731 #1020002 android:id/content}
                  android.widget.RelativeLayout{98e594a V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1584}
                    androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView{a0cc0bb V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1584}
D/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.LinearLayout{5c939d8 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1584}
                      android.widget.LinearLayout{b5da131 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,158}
                        androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{ae0c016 V.ED..... ........ 26,26-653,132}
                        androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{33cad97 V.ED..... ........ 705,26-1054,132}
                      androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{7841b84 VFED..... ........ 26,184-1054,1558 #7f07008f app:id/rvId}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{fba1f6d VFE...C.. ........ 0,0-1028,184 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{320c7a2 V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{b148c33 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{ce96bf0 VFE...C.. ........ 0,187-1028,371 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{9e64569 V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{867bbee V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{781b88f VFE...C.. ........ 0,374-1028,558 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.TextView{611571c V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{994cf25 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{717a8fa VFE...C.. ........ 0,561-1028,745 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{5eb4eab V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{a6ac908 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{ce838a1 VFE...C.. ........ 0,748-1028,932 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{da75ac6 V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{90e2a87 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.LinearLayout{7676db4 VFE...C.. ........ 0,935-1028,1119 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{7aebddd V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{92e5d52 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{898e823 VFE...C.. ........ 0,1122-1028,1306 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{de7b120 V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{25e5ad9 V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
                        android.widget.LinearLayout{eb0fc9e VFE...C.. ........ 0,1309-1028,1493 #7f07008e app:id/rowId}
                          android.widget.TextView{e87e37f V.ED..... ........ 13,13-650,171 #7f070079 app:id/name}
                          android.widget.ImageView{a66bf4c V.ED..... ........ 676,13-1015,171 #7f070061 app:id/flag}
D/FragmentManager:             androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer{cd0cb95 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1080,147 #7f070029 app:id/action_bar_container}
                  androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar{d2c44aa V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,147 #7f070027 app:id/action_bar}
                    androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{e41389b V.ED..... ........ 42,38-382,109}
                    androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView{3e68438 V.E...... ........ 1080,0-1080,147}
                  androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContextView{bf8c11 G.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07002f app:id/action_context_bar}
          android.view.View{4620176 V.ED..... ........ 0,1794-1080,1920 #1020030 android:id/navigationBarBackground}
          android.view.View{170c377 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1080,63 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}
      Looper (main, tid 2) {d9babe4}
        (Total messages: 0, polling=false, quitting=false)
      AutofillManager:
        sessionId: 2147483647
        state: UNKNOWN
D/FragmentManager:     context: com.example.countriesdata.activities.ListActivity@cc8ca22
        client: com.example.countriesdata.activities.ListActivity@cc8ca22 (android.os.BinderProxy@dd59a96)
        enabled: false
        enabledAugmentedOnly: false
        hasService: true
        hasCallback: false
        onInvisibleCalled false
        last autofilled data: null
        id of last fill UI shown: null
        tracked views: null
        fillable ids: null
        entered ids: null
        save trigger id: null
        save on finish(): false
        options: logLvl=0, compatMode=false, augmented=false
        compat mode enabled: false
D/FragmentManager:     debug: false verbose: false
      Autofill Compat Mode: false
      No ContentCaptureManager
      ResourcesManager:
        cached apks: 0 [cache disabled]
        total apks: 1
        resources: 4
        resource impls: 3
      Local FragmentActivity cc8ca22 State:
D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=true mResumed=true mStopped=false  Active Fragments in fffd84d:
      CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
          mFragmentId=#7f070063 mContainerId=#7f070063 mTag=null
          mState=1 mWho=ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5 mBackStackNesting=1
          mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
          mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
          mRetainInstance=false mUserVisibleHint=true
          mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{fffd84d in HostCallbacks{c64bf02}}
          mHost=androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@c64bf02
          mArguments=Bundle[{countriesList=null}]
          Child FragmentManager{6a42013 in CountryFragment{3ded6a8}}:
            FragmentManager misc state:
D/FragmentManager:           mHost=androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@c64bf02
              mContainer=androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$4@759a250
              mParent=CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
              mCurState=1 mStateSaved=false mStopped=false mDestroyed=false
      Added Fragments:
        #0: CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
      Back Stack:
        #0: BackStackEntry{a7eac49 #0}
          mName=null mIndex=0 mCommitted=true
          Operations:
            Op #0: ADD CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
      Back Stack Indices:
        #0: BackStackEntry{a7eac49 #0}
      FragmentManager misc state:
        mHost=androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@c64bf02
        mContainer=androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@c64bf02
        mCurState=4 mStateSaved=false mStopped=false mDestroyed=false
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.countriesdata, PID: 14691
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070063 (com.example.countriesdata:id/fragments_container) for fragment CountryFragment{3ded6a8 (ab54e82e-6114-4343-90ec-ed8edf4125b5) id=0x7f070063}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**ListActivity** - here the transaction starts

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListAdapter.ItemClickListener {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        Fragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragments_container, menuFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**The destination Fragment**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    int population;
    double area, gini;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fragments_container">
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The Fragment's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout ` as Fragment container

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as Fragment container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    < FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragments_container">
    </FrameLayout >

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Tried it now. I still get the same Exception.